# iCarousel is getting stick when starting to scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, carousel

[image: Getting stick here]I have implemented iCarousel's this methods as,

It is getting stick at beginning and after seconds it allows me to scroll. And also i don't want the images to be overlapped while scrolling i want them all to be having equal distance between each item.

What is wrong in this code? or i am missing anything?

```
-(void)addiCarousel
{
    carousel.frame = CGRectMake(324, 50, 375, 195);
    [self.view addSubview:carousel];
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg", nil];
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [carousel reloadData];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [items count];
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

 //   if (view == nil)
   // {
        view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(649, 50, 375 , 195)] autorelease];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        view.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
        view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

//    }

     ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.items objectAtIndex:index]];

    NSLog(@"index : %d",index);
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.items objectAtIndex:index]);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: it has a method to define the width of each image in carousel.. try using that.. also show a screen shot having overlapped or the issue u r getting

Comment: it is not getting scroll at beginning.It is stick there and after some time while i continue try scrolling it gets scroll.screen shot wont be able to define that

Comment: 375*190 this might be the size.they are coming form webservice so for now i took this dimenstions

Comment: you can resize the images from the services, and use them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding below code it stop getting stick and gave smooth scrolling

It was missing,

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel

    //set opacity based on distance from camera
    view.alpha = 1.0 - fminf(fmaxf(offset, 0.0), 1.0);

    //do 3d transform
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = carousel.perspective;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI / 8.0, 0, 1.0, 0);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, 0.0, offset * carousel.itemWidth);
}
```

along with `carousel.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Might help others.

Answer (score 2):

have you used the below method

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
//usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
return 240;
}
```

this info is given in the tutorial.. and you can use

```
    [carousal scrollToItemAtIndex:3 animated:NO];
```

so that it shows the 3 pic at the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the reloadData call after creating the carousel, and instead add the carousel as a subview after you've set up the items array.